# Access of dataframe element leads to crash

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, tuples

Columns of **df_alter**

```
Index(['premise', 'hypothesis', 'label'], dtype='object')
```

For the dataframe operation below:

```
  KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-557-204d154f2f70> in <module>
          2 print(len(df_alter['hypothesis']))
          3 for idx in range(len(df_alter['hypothesis'])):
    ----> 4     print(df_alter['hypothesis'][idx])
          5     df_alter['hypothesis'][idx] = re.sub(r'\bshe\b', r'they', df_alter['hypothesis'][idx])
          6     df_alter['hypothesis'][idx] = re.sub(r'\bhe\b', r'they', df_alter['hypothesis'][idx])
```

I see the followinng crash:

```
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    851 
    852         elif key_is_scalar:
--> 853             return self._get_value(key)
    854 
    855         if is_hashable(key):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
    959 
    960         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
--> 961         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
    962         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)
    963 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:
-> 3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3083 
   3084         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 1
```

What could be wrong in the way I am accessing df elements?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with join both regexes by `|` instead your loop:

```
print (df_alter)
       hypothesis
0  aa he sss heap
1    she are shed

df_alter['hypothesis'] = df_alter['hypothesis'].str.replace(r'\b(she|he)\b', 
                                                            r'they', 
                                                            regex=True)
print (df_alter)
         hypothesis
0  aa they sss heap
1     they are shed
```

EDIT: For more general solution use:

```
d = {'they': ['she','he'],
     'new': ['aa']}

d1 = {r"\b({})\b".format("|".join(re.escape(x) for x in v)): k for k, v in d.items()}
print (d1)
{'\\b(she|he)\\b': 'they', '\\b(aa)\\b': 'new'}


df_alter['hypothesis'] = df_alter['hypothesis'].replace(d1, regex=True)
print (df_alter)
          hypothesis
0  new they sss heap
1      they are shed
```

Comment: For other regex replacements fo I need to add extra lines or is there a way to combine them maybe through a list of searchstrings = ['reg1', 'reg2] ?

Comment: @user17609416 - all values are replaced to `they` ?

Comment: no different strings could be they, them theirs, people, persons etc.

Comment: @user17609416 - First in pandas loop is not necessary, added non loop solution.